# In react Native ,I have written program for creating bars which will randomly create different size of the bars

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

when I'm running this program in expo app it bundling process gets completed but still not showing any output and it crashes and same program is running in the chrome and display's the bars . Anyone knows why it is getting crashed

```
const [len, setlen] = useState(20);
  const id = uuid();
  const newArray = () => {
    const array = [];
    while (array.length < len) {
      const NewBar = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200) + 1;
      //   console.log(array)
      if (array.indexOf(NewBar) === -1) array.push(NewBar);
    }
    setBars(array);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    newArray();
    // console.log(bars);
  }, []);
```

```
return (
    <View style={styles.barCon}>
      <SortingHeader resetArray={resetArray} />
      <Text>Bars</Text>
     
      <View style={styles.allBars}>
        {bars.map((value, idx) => (
          <View key={idx}>
            <View
              key={idx}
              style={{
                height: `${value}px`,
                marginLeft: 2,
                 marginRight: 2,
                width: 10,
                backgroundColor: "blue",
                fontSize: 5,
              }}
            ></View>
          </View>
        ))}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Would be great if you published the error here also.

In the meanwhile, I can see one issue: in React-native we don't use "px" when specifying height or weight of an element.

Comment: wait a moment please i'll try

Comment: Bro still it is getting crash i don't know why

Comment: do you have error on the screen?

Comment: Bro that px one idea was awsm it worked ,thanks for the help